# locking out users, not allowing mysql update

Tags: php, mysql

I need to lock out a user when another user is already on the page.

It should still be possible to view the post and add things but the function in mysql to UPDATE should not be allowed as it might overwrite data.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have been killing myself trying to come up with an answer.

System uses php and mysql. Users are already receiving a message when another user is on the same page. All I need is to find a way to 'disable' mysql UPDATE...

Thank you in advance!

Youri

Answer (score 0):

Set a session variable and track it. Say the name of the variable is "engaged"

User X visits the page, if(engaged==1){readonly} else{ read_and_write; set engaged=1}

Comment: And how some user will know another user is editing page now?

Comment: huh ? the engaged variable will be set to 1. When the user is done with the page, reset the variable.

Comment: Are there any global session in php? Which are shared between different users.

Comment: sorry wasn't clear, I assumed DB sessions :(  If you save sessions in the db, you can have a variable to track it. The variable can reference a column in the session table along with the page name / module name per user.

Comment: hi I have done that. The user is now getting a warning that another user in on the page. But how do you disable the mysql UPDATE function when this happens?

Comment: sorry I dont understand that Stewie

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to handle this is the Database. If you start acquiring and holding locks, especially with web clients, you're entering a world of pain!

This is how I handle it:

First, Create a table, let's call it `RecordLock` (`Table_name`, `Record_id`, `timeout`) Let timeout be a unix timestamp (to save all the mucking about with datetimes) Let 'table_name' and 'Record_Id' be a composite primary key.

Whenever a user loads a page, do the following:

1. `DELETE FROM RecordLock WHERE timeout < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` This is to clear out any expired locks.
2. Insert a record into Record Lock (table_name, record_id, timestamp+timeout) where timeout is the number of seconds a lock is valid for. This is to ensure a record isn't locked forever if someone walks away from their browser or disconnects from the internet. You can also `SELECT` to see if the lock exists, but be aware that a record can be inserted between your `SELECT` and `INSERT` depending on how you are handling transactions.

If the insert fails, someone has already acquired the lock (due to the PK on table and record id) Your application should be aware that the record is read_only and disallow saves, as well as alert the user that the record is being edited right now.

If the insert succeeds, you have the lock. 
3. When the current user closes or saves the record, delete the record in the RecordLock (otherwise it will just expire and potentially block other users longer than need be)

Comment: okay, I have done it sort of. The problem now is that when the user pressed the back button on the browser that they get the old form back and then this can be saved again. Help